# which license enforces giving credit to author

Tags: open-source, licensing

I want my software to be GPL (put source code along with your files when you sell it)

but still anyone who (uses, update,sell, derivate) it. gives us credit (for making the core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPL ensures you still get credit.  Modifiers are required to retain your copyright statements.

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IWantCredit